# openstack, pkgcloud and node js

Tags: node.js, openstack, pkgcloud

I am using pkg cloud in node js

```
var pkgcloud = require('pkgcloud'),
```

_ = require('lodash');

// create our client with your openstack credentials

```
var client = pkgcloud.compute.createClient({
provider: 'openstack',
username: 'your-user-name',
password: 'your-password',
region: 'RegionOne', //default for DevStack, might be different on other 
OpenStack distributions
authUrl: 'https://your-identity-service'
```

});

// first we're going to get our flavors

```
client.getFlavors(function (err, flavors) {
if (err) {
console.dir(err);
 return;
 }
```

})

with valid credentials but i am not able to connect openstack.

I think some connection problem with node js and pkgcloud like importing .ssh file or some prerequisites to solve this . Can you guide me to solve this issue